# jQuery addClass not overwriting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This has been answered quite a few times before and all the responses seem to point to specificity of the CSS, but as far as I can tell, that does not seem to be the case here.

HTML

```
<button class="flex-item color-2">A</button>
<button class="flex-item color-2">B</button>
<button class="flex-item color-2">C</button>
```

JS

```
$("button.color-2").hover( function(){
    $(this).addClass("color-1 bg-2");
}, function(){
    //$(this).removeClass("color-1").removeClass("bg-2");
});
```

Developer Tools Output

[image]

I did change the background to be a class as I realized I had the background specified elsewhere.

Now, when the javascript adds the classes, the background overwrites, but the color does not.

Does addClass not take precedence over pre-defined colors?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just use `background-color` so specificity is not an issue?  Specificity is what is causing the problem with the bg.  The text color issue is probably because `.color-2` is applied after `.color-1`

Comment: what do you expect to happen?

Comment: check for other styles that affecting to that elements

Comment: No it does not take precedence, it will just add the class and normal CSS cascading rules will apply, you may want to remove the existing `color-2` class or adjust your CSS files so `color-1` has preference. Setting css attributes with `.css('background-color','red')` WILL take precedence since they're added inline to the element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question

"Does addClass not take precedence over pre-defined colors?"

Jquery addClass has nothing to do with precedence at all as far as I know. The precedence of your css is defined in your css.

For example, the color 2 takes precedence because it is on line 216 and your #fff is on line 215

If you want the added class to take precedence then you need to define it better in your css. Either define it later in the css file or define it with a more specific selector, you could also use !important but you might get into a situation later where !important is not good enough so I would avoid it for now

Answer (score 2):

that wont overwrite because  'color-1 bg-2' classes defined before 'flex-item color-2'.. 
order your classes in your css.

or

you can use !important on 'color-1 bg-2'  classes

.bg-2{display: block !important}

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$(this).addClass("color-1 bg-2").removeClass("color-2");
```

Because your `color-2` class affects the color, just remove it..